# What happend with BCH SV and BCH ABC

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I hope I ask in the right place. Since both are have same source. So, what's going on with BCH? Why before the hard fork the price is sky rocketing but after the fork. It sink like a sinking boat?

Comment: Price discussions are off topic for this site, please see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 19):

Looks like ABC win this rally. ABC have more [hash power](https://cash.coin.dance/blocks/hashrate) and more supporters.
[image]

I like this approach to explain:

> BTC = real Bitcoin
>
> BTCC = real fake
>
> Bitcoin BCH = fake fake Bitcoin
>
> BCHSV = real (?) fake fake Bitcoin
>
> BCHABC = fake (?) fake fake Bitcoin

https://twitter.com/FedericoTenga/status/1063430370308354048

Comment: OK,  but how does the relative fortunes of the real fake fake vs the fake fake fake cause the price of the fake fake to sink like a sinking sink? Isn't that what the question was asking?

Comment: can you elaborate your answer. I still don't get it. Thanks.

Comment: Before hard fork the price is usually rising because people hope to get 2 coin in different network instead of one. We saw it before creation of Ethereum's DAO fork in July 2016 (Ethereum Classic story), Bitcoin Cash and some others. After hard fork people choose strongest network (much support of developers and services, more hashrate), which leads to dump the price.

Comment: The behavior formula is simple = You get some kind of entity > You wait until this entity clones itself and and sell the one (or both) you consider unnecessary in the hope of exceeding the initial investment > Possible but not guaranteed profit. I think there is no Bitcoin ABC in future, because the winner keeps the original ticker symbol. For example Kraken and Huobi already assign BCH ticker to Bitcoin Cash ABC.